# Linq validator in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, linq

I'd like to write my own validator for linq syntax.
I've written simple grammar in BNF notation (example of from method below):

```
<from> ::= from <item> in <data>
<item> ::= <letter> <number> | <letter> <number> <item> | <letter> | `<letter> <item> | '_'` 
<letter> ::= [A-Z] | [a-z]
<number> ::= [0-9]
<symbol> ::= '%', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '==', '/'
```

I know that isn't all I need, but it'll be growing with writing my validator.

The simple file I'd like to test my validator:

```
 var query_orderby1 = from c in svcContext.ContactSet
                      where !c.CreditLimit.Equals(null)
                      orderby c.CreditLimit descending
```

I'd like to write my validator in javascript and I don't have idea how to deal with this problem. My first thought was to read this code from file and parse it by functions I've written. I've declared terminal symbols But I'm not sure it's the best way to deal with it. Any suggestions how to deal with it or should I change technology for 'more' objective language like python or java?

Comment: where do you use the linq string?

Comment: That is a bit broad of a question, i think.

Comment: Yes this is far too broad I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to *generate* a parser from your grammar.

[Peg.js](https://pegjs.org/) is awesome for this kind of thing. You can make a grammar (kind of like EBNF) and generate JavaScript code for the parser.

Peg.js even has an [online editor](https://pegjs.org/online) so you can prototype grammar in the browser (with some sample input) before you extract it to build your proper reusable parser.

You can then put your LINQ code through the parser and that should be enough to validate it.

But you should know that creating a parser for a language, even a simple one is probably more difficult than you think, but I hope you do it because it's a very rewarding and educational experience.

I already searched for 'Peg.js linq grammar' hoping I might find an existing grammar that you could reuse, but there doesn't seem to be any.

If you make your own Peg.js grammar please share it!